# HDMI Laptop to TV No Audio from TV

Tags: laptop, hdmi, tv, gateway

I have a T Series Gateway laptop. When I use the HDMI port to look at video on a remote screen no sound gets transmitted to the remote screen's speakers.

Answer (score 4):

HDMI audio is often implemented as a separate audio device than the onboard sound card. Have you tried switching the default audio device to the HDMI output?

1. Right-click on the speaker icon in your system tray, or `Control Panel` -> `Sound`
2. Under playback, select the HDMI output, and click `Set Default`
3. Some audio may switch immediately, some may require a restart of the application to take effect
4. When you're done, set the default back to the original device to restore normal audio if it doesn't do so automatically.

.
[image]

Comment: I JUST had this issue this last weekend, and that indeed was the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Just right-click on the sound icon on the taskbar (by the time), click on the PlayBack tab, then Right-click on either HDMI or Speakerphones and select "Set as default" to switch between TV and PC speakers

Note: You might need to close and restart any applications like Media player, VLC, Mozilla etc. For instance, say you were listening to iTunes, then hooked your pc to your tv and followed the staps above, there'd be no sound coming from the iTunes cos it's still set on Speakers/Headphones. So you'd need to close it and restart it